# Is there a contradiction hiding in this alternative set theory with 3 axioms?

Tags: logic, foundations, alternative-set-theories

Let us take as a vocabulary the $\in$ relation (is an element of), and a single unary predicate $C$, where $Cx$ is read "$x$ is constructible" or "$x$ is a constructible set" (I'm making this up, but the term seems appropriate). We may then write down an alterative set theory with three intuitive axioms (one of them an axiom schema):

1. Extensionality: $$\forall X \,\forall X'\;:\; (\forall x\,:\, x \in X \longleftrightarrow x \in X') \to X = X'.$$

   (I.e.: Objects with the same elements are equal.)
2. Schema of construction: For any formula $\varphi$ which **does not contain C**, if $\varphi$ has free variables $x$ and $\overline{y} = (y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_k)$, IF
   $$
   \forall \overline{y} \, \forall x \;:\; (Cy_1 \land \cdots \land Cy_k \land \varphi(x,\overline{y})) \to Cx
   $$
   THEN
   $$
   \forall \overline{y} \, \exists X \, \forall x \,:\, x \in X \longleftrightarrow \varphi(x,\overline{y}).
   $$
   In other words, if it is possible to deduce that $x$ is constructible from only the fact that $y_i$ are constructible and $\varphi(x,\overline{y})$, then the set $X = \{x \mid \varphi(x,\overline{y})\}$ exists.
3. Constructible sets are those with constructible elements:

   $$\forall X \; : \; CX \longleftrightarrow (\forall x \;:\; x \in X \to Cx).$$

It seems to me I can deduce many of the axioms of ZF from these: at least, pairing, union, power set, and specification.* So I am thinking there must be a contradiction lurking somewhere. The question:

**(i) Is there an (obvious) contradiction in these three axoims?**

For instance, we could try to encode Russell's paradox. It can't translate directly, since if we just assume "$x \in x$", it doesn't follow that $Cx$. And one cannot play tricks with "the set of all constructible sets that don't contain themselves" because $C$ is not allowed in $\varphi$ in the comprehension schema.

However, there does seem to be something fishy going on: in ZFC, well-founded induction is a theorem, and well-founded induction cannot be true here or else we could prove that all sets are constructible (using axiom 3). At that point, (2) reduces to unrestricted comprehension and the theory becomes inconsistent.

I would also like to know:

**(ii) Is this theory similar to any existing alternative set theories?**

When I wrote down these axioms this afternoon, I was trying to formalize the intuitive justification for the axioms of ZFC, namely, that every axiom constructs bigger sets out of smaller sets which have already been defined.

*For pairing, if $A$ and $B$ are constructible, and $x = A$ or $x = B$ then $x$ is constructible. The other axioms I mentioned (union, power set, and specification) use axiom (3): For union, if $A$ is constructible and $x \in a$, $a \in A$, $x$ is constructible. For power set, if $A$ is constructible and $B \subseteq A$, then every $x \in B$ is constructible so $B$ is constructible. For specification, if $x \in A$ and$ \varphi(x)$, and $A$ is constructible, then in particular $x \in A$ so $x$ is constructible.

Comment: What does "constructible" mean here?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You mean intuitively? Intuitively I mean something like "well-founded" -- it is built from "smaller" sets which have already been constructed.

Comment: Comprehension is usually the name for a different Schema. What you call Comprehension is a modification of the Schema that's usually called Replacement. It would be better if you changed the words. Your Q is, I think.  whether it is consistent with ZF that there  exists a transitive set or  proper  class $C=\{x:Cx\}$  that satisfies  the relativizations to C of Extensionality and "unlimited Replacement", (transitivity of C is your Axiom (3): Members of C are subsets of C.)

Comment: Thanks. Moreover another question: writing $\exists X$ we mean $\exists X: CX$? I.e. our objects are this special-sets? These formulas are defining these versions of the symbols $\in$ and $=$ I suppose. I don't get actually the real difference between $\exists X$ and $CX$. However really nice "question"

Comment: @DanielWainfleet OK, I renamed (2) "construction" to avoid confusion with the usual comprehension. But I am not sure (2) is the same as replacement. Also, maybe it is inconsistent with ZFC that C exists because ZFC would prove by epsilon-induction that every element satisfies C.

Comment: @Tancredi Thanks, the first $x$ was supposed to be an upper case $X$, that was a typo. For your other question, no, I mean to make a distinction between $\exists X$ and $\exists X : CX$, but I am not sure it matters everywhere. In axiom (2) I think $\exists X : CX$ would be equivalent since we can prove $CX$ for that newly constructed set by axiom (3).

Comment: I am thinking of constructible sets ($CX$) as being the "real" sets, but the $\varphi$ in the schema of construction doe snot have access to the knowledge about which objects are $C$s and which aren't. So this second axiom says something kindof funny about only being able to construct a set if you can prove all of its elements are sets already.

Comment: (2) is definitely not the same as the usual Replacement  Schema!

Comment: So, @6005, you are actually defining a subclass of the Sets and you are telling which is in and which is out? Don't want absolutely to be tedious, but I think it is pretty important. When I write $\exists X$ in set theory I mean a set does exist. If your quantification are free I suppose you are actually inside the set theory, so it's pretty confusing what $\in$ and $=$ really are. Thank you

Comment: If you can prove ZF, then the third axiom is redundant by a simple $\in$-induction.

Comment: @Tancredi Yes. In fact, it's important that you can't conclude, for instance, that $Cx$ from $x \notin x$ (or Russell's paradox arises). So while $C$ is not true of all "sets", it should be true of any sets that we construct and/or care about. The $C$ is a way of describing sets that are constructive and not self-containing or self-referential. Quantification is always over the entire model (not just where $C$ holds).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. I think we have to clarify specifically what "proves ZF" means -- proves the axioms exactly? or only for the restriction of the theory to elements such that $C$ holds? And $\epsilon$-induction may hold but only for properties not mentioning $C$.

Comment: No, $\in$-induction has nothing to do with the separation schema here. Once you can prove enough of ZF, then just by virtue of being well-founded you can simply ask what is the least $\alpha$ such that $x\in V_\alpha$ and $\lnot Cx$. But now all the elements of $x$ are of lower rank and therefore satisfy $C$, so by the third axiom $Cx$ holds. Therefore there is no such $\alpha$.

Comment: I meant: Are we **inside** the set theory? I don't understand what are your intuitive object. In set theory they are sets, so if you write $\exists x$ it suffices, you don't have to use a predicate "is a set" like $\exists x: Sx$. I hope to have been clear in explain my doubt.
I guess if in your theory you have also badsets for whom doesn't hold $C$, I guess them would be useless, **unless** we are actually inside the real set theory and are talking about "some sets are c. some other are not"

Comment: What is the order of operations in your condition to your second axiom?  $(\dots \land \dots) \to \dots$ or $\dots \land (\dots \to \dots)$ ?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It seems that amounts to a proof that this theory does not imply ZF -- if it does indeed, an answer saying as much would be helpful.

Comment: @Tancredi The theory is just exactly what I wrote. It's a first-order theory with two symbols and those axioms. But let me take another stab at my intuition: all objects are sets, but only some sets ($Cx$) are constructible. We don't know a priori which sets are constructible and which aren't, but we know that if we can describe a collection of constructible sets then that collection is also constructible (axiom schema (2)). In this theory in fact we can show there are non-constructible sets: if all sets were constructible, then Russell's paradox would apply in axiom (2). [contd]

Comment: [contd] These bad sets, for which $C$ doesn't hold, are probably useless but they serve a logical purpose, namely they are hypothetical sets for which we can't prove they are constructible, and thus we can't deduce that just because $x \in x$ is a well-defined predicate, any $x$ satisfying the predicate would be constructible.

Comment: @6005 Thank you very much for your patience, so your objects are sets of the common ZFC? And some of them satisfy the predicate $C$?

Comment: @Tancredi No, the objects are "sets" of this alternative set theory. I don't think they will be the same as the sets in ZFC, I expect there are more sets in this theory.

Comment: @DanielV $a \land b \to c$ means $(a \land b) \to c$. I thought this was standard but I'll edit to add parens.

Comment: Perfect, I was guessing that, so you are defining $\in$ and $=$, ok. But I think $\exists X$ does not make sense. Don't want to be unpolite, but try to reread your theory dropping all $C$, as we constantly do in set theory. A set is a thing which exists. Russell "set" does not exists, we don't have in set theory an object "Russel" which **then** don't satisfy a predicate of "setness"

Comment: In formula 2, when you write $\forall \overline{y} \, \exists X \, \forall x \; :\;x \in X \longleftrightarrow \varphi(x,\overline{y})$, do you mean $\forall \overline{y} \, \exists X \, CX \land \forall x \; :\;x \in X \longleftrightarrow \varphi(x,\overline{y})$ ?

Comment: @DanielV I originally wrote it that way, but then realized Axiom 3 implies $CX$ so it is not necessary for axiom 2 to give that explicitly.

Comment: @Tancredi I'm not sure what you are getting at. Think about it this way: Naive set theory is inconsistent. ZFC is not obviously so. *Why* is ZFC not inconsistent? There is actually good intuitive justification, if you read up on the philosophy behind ZFC axioms: namely, that all axioms only create a new set out of previously defined things. That is, you can only create a set if its elements were already created. And that is exactly what my $C$ here is attempting to formalize. Now you say, why don't we just identify $C$ with all sets? Well for one thing that would be inconsistent, and [contd]

Comment: for another, that would defeat the purpose of this attempt at set theory, which is formalizing the idea that in ZFC sets are only created out of previously-created sets. If this set theory is stronger than ZFC, then it is also more natural and general. And if it is not as strong, that would be good to know too.

Comment: Well, why so don't put $C$ on our set theory, then? Defining a subclass of Set to know which sets are "more"-constructive. I understand making an axiomatic theory which construct only constructible elements, that's perfect. I understand mining inside ZFC a $C$ subclass defining who is in and who is out. I don't understand recreating a (apparently) similar version of naive ZF (which seems to produce incoherence even if not by $C$-objects) and then make substantially another theory

Comment: @Tancredi Wel, if you can prove it's incoherent, that would be great :)

Comment: @6005 did you understand the rest of my question? I think it's the most important part

Comment: @Tancredi No, I did not understand it.

Comment: That's ok, I wasn't able to explain what I was meaning

Comment: You may be interested in George Boolos' axiomatization of the iterative conception of sets, published in his well-known (and aptly titled) "The Iterative Conception of Set" (it was reprinted in his *Logic, Logic, and Logic*). He not only axiomatizes the notion, but shows how to derive most of Z's axioms from it (he also argues that Replacement and Choice are not derivable from this conception).

Comment: What do you think about [this alternative axiomatization](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53757897#53757897)?

Comment: @user76284 I like that as well! It seems roughly equivalent?

Comment: @6005 I've posted a question about it here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354662/how-strong-is-this-set-theory.

Comment: The variant @user76284 came up with is inconsistent. You're lucky that yours doesn't seem inconsistent (yet)!

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Could you share your reasoning why this isn't set theory? Are all questions about alternative set theoretic axioms invalid for the set-theory tag?

Comment: What if you change $C x$ to $x \in V$, where $V$ is a new constant? It seems like you can then prove infinity by using $V$ as an inductive set.

Comment: @user76284 Interesting modification! Maybe we can prove that version is equivalent to Ackermann? However my axiom (3) implies in that case that $V \in V$ which is a bit worrisome, because then we can construct sets like $\{V \}$ etc. I think it would be better to not have $V \in V$.

Comment: You’re [probably right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354733/can-ackermann-theory-minus-foundation-minus-class-comprehension-permit-allowing?noredirect=1#comment890176_354733). In that case we should probably think about what’s the [simplest axiom we can add](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207352/simplest-axiom-that-entails-the-existence-of-an-infinite-set?r=SearchResults) that gives us infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your theory bears large similarity to Ackermann's. Notice that Ackermann's originally used a one place predicate symbol $M$ standing for "is a set", later on the constant symbol $V$ became to be used instead (which is in some sense a relatively *stronger* approach as far as fragments of Ackermann's is concerned). You can think of your predicate $C$ as the predicate $M$ of original Ackermann's. Definitely your theory proves the following axioms of Ackermann's set theory: Extensionality, both Completeness axioms for $V$, and all instances of set construction (reflection scheme); but it adds to it, the principle that every subclass of $V$ is a set (your third axiom) but on the other hand not having class comprehension, your theory cannot prove existence of $V$ [which would correspond to the class of all $C$ sets] and because of that I'd conjecture (not really sure) that it cannot prove infinity. Actually there is a similar question that I've posed about Ackermann, where I've posed the challenging axiom of every proper subclass of $V$ being a set (i.e. an element of $V$) and I added it to Ackemrann - foundation - class comprehension. I don't think anyone came with an inconsistency with it, and there it proved even infinity, and it might even be as strong as the original Ackermann's system.  I think your theory here is more benign since it doesn't even construct a universal class. I think it is consistent and it is equivalent to Ackermann - foundation- class comprehension with having its primitive being the original primitive of Ackermann which is the one place predicate symbol $M$. And I think it might be equivalent to $PA$. You need to refer to fragments of Ackermann's set theory!

Note: actually I've also asked almost exactly the same as your question, but with the slight addition of infinity, and *freedom* on parameters (on the *antecedent* as well as on the consequent of set construction) See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251691/is-this-simple-class-theory-equi-interpretable-with-zfc)

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful information, I like the connection to Ackermann and to some other questions you've asked.

Comment: If it cannot prove infinity, this would be a nice case of $\omega$- incompleteness : since $C(\emptyset)$ and $C(x)\Rightarrow C(x\cup \lbrace x \rbrace)$, the proposition $Int(x) \Rightarrow C(x)$ is true but unprovable in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Update (2023): this theory is consistent, and moreover, it does not prove infinity.

To show the theory is consistent, we will construct the following model.
Let $H$ be the set of [Hereditarily finite sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set) (i.e. $\varnothing$, $\{\varnothing\}$, $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$, $\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$, and so on).
$(H, \in)$ is a model of all of the ZFC axioms except infinity.
Now consider any [ultrapower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) of $H$, denoted ${}^*H$; formally, the set of infinite sequences of hereditarily finite sets, modulo some choice of nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$. As usual with ultraproducts, all constants, sets, functions, and relations (including $\in$ and $=$) lift from $H$ to ${}^*H$, and we denote the lift of an object $A$ by ${}^*A$. Also, $H$ is thought of as a subset of ${}^H$, via the embedding $h \mapsto (h, h, h, \ldots)$. Now identify $C$ with $H$, i.e. $C$ is true precisely of the elements of $H$. I claim that
$$
(^{*}H, ^{*}\in, C = H)
$$
is a model of axioms 1-3 in the theory in the OP.
Moreover, it does not prove infinity, because $C$ is true only of finite sets.

The proof below relies heavily on the transfer principle for ultrapowers (Łoś's theorem): all first-order facts about $H$ are true about $^{*}H$, and vice versa, as long as those facts do not mention the predicate $C$.

#### Proof

We have to show this model given above satisfies the three axioms.

- Axiom 1, extensionality is for free by the transfer principle since extensionality holds in $H$.
- For Axiom 3, hereditarily finite sets have hereditarily finite elements, so that part is fine. For the converse, consider a set $X$ in $(^{*}H, ^{*}\in, H)$ all of whose elements are in $H$. Represented as a sequence it can be written as
  $$
  X = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)
  $$
  If $X \ne \varnothing$, then every index of $X$ (modulo a set of indices not in the ultrafilter) has an element, so we can define a $Y$ such that $Y \in X$
  $$
  Y = (y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots)
  $$
  Moreover, we can choose $Y$ such that each $y_i$ has maximum rank.
  By hypothesis, every element of $X$ is in $H$, so $Y \in H$.
  This means there is some hereditarily finite $h$ such that $y_i = h$ for all $i$ (modulo a set of indices not in the ultrafilter).
  But as $y_i$ was chosen of maximal rank, if the rank of $h$ is $n$ then all indices of $X$ (modulo a set of indices not in the ultrafilter) are of rank at most $n + 1$, and there are only finitely many such sets, so $X$ must be equal to one of these sets. I.e., the indices are partitioned into finitely many parts, and only one of those is in the ultrafilter, and $X$ equals that set.
  So this proves $X$ is itself actually in $H$.
- Axiom 2, construction, is the most interesting one. Here is where we rely most heavily on the transfer principle for arbitrary formulas. Let us show the axiom is satisfied for any choice of formula $\varphi$. Fix any vector of hereditarily finite sets $\overline{y}$.
  The hypothesis, applied to these $\overline{y}$, tells us that
  $$
  \forall x \varphi(x,\overline{y})) \to Cx
  $$
  Now, $\overline{y}$ only consists of hereditarily finite sets, and all such sets can be defined uniquely by plain formulas of set theory (for example, $\varnothing$ is the set containing no elements, $\{\varnothing\}$ is the set containing one element which contains nothing, and so on).
  So we can replace $\varphi(x, \overline{y})$ with an equivalent formula $\varphi_{\overline{y}}(x)$ which only has one free variable, and which implies $Cx$.
  Now this formula also does not mention $C$, so by the transfer principle it is true of elements of $H$ in $(^{*}H, ^{*}\in, H)$ if and only if it is true in the base model $(H, \in)$.
  But as a lemma, the only unary predicates which remain the same in the base model and in the ultraproduct are the finite predicates. This is because if $\varphi_{\overline{y}}(x)$ were true of infinitely many $x$ values in $H$, then we could construct an infinite sequence of those $x$ values resulting in a sequence in $^{*}H$ satisfying $\varphi$ but not in $C$.
  So $\varphi_{\overline{y}}(x)$ is in fact equivalent to membership in a finite set, i.e. it is equivalent to a membership formula
  $$
      x \in X
  $$
  for some $X \in H$. Now this almost proves the conclusion we want; it proves, for this particular choice of $\overline{y}$, that
  $$
  \exists X \, \forall x \,:\, x \in X \longleftrightarrow \varphi(x,\overline{y}).
  $$
  To finally get our conclusion, we use the transfer principle again to relativize this statement to $H$:
  $$
  \exists X \in H \, \forall x \in H \,:\, x \in X \longleftrightarrow \varphi^H(x,\overline{y}).
  $$
  where $\varphi^H$ is the relativization. Now we can finally close out the quantification on $\overline{y}$ and apply the transfer principle in reverse to get
  $$
  \forall \overline{y} \, \exists X \, \forall x \,:\, x \in X \longleftrightarrow \varphi(x,\overline{y}),
  $$
  as desired.

#### Notes

The reason this theory does not prove infinity but [Ackermann set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory) does seems to be due to the lack of a class of all sets $V$ -- which is replaced by the predicate $C$. Indeed, in the model above, there does not exist an element $V$ whose elements are exactly the sets $H$; any such element would also have to include infinitely many non-standard elements.

However, adding $V$ directly to this theory results in inconsistency. Once we have $V$, Axiom 3 becomes suspect as it implies the consequence $V \in V$. From here, we can apply axiom 2, for example, to the formula
$$
x \in a \land x \not \in x
$$
where $a$ is some constant. Since $x \in a$ and $Ca$ implies $Cx$, the premise holds. The conclusion lets us construct the set of sets $x$ such that $x \in a \land x \not \in x$ for any $a$. But in particular we can do this for $a = V$, so we have Russell's paradox on $V$.