# Is this simple class theory equi-interpretable with ZFC?

Tags: first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

The question here is about the consistency of a rather very simply presented theory and if it is equivalent to ZFC.

The theory is a first order theory of classes, so it has its primitives being equality and membership, with a new primitive one place predicate added that is "set" to denote "..is a set". Now the axioms are those of Extensionality written exactly as in ZFC. An axiom stating that every class is a set if and only if it is a class of sets. A comprehension axiom schema stating that whenever a formula holds strictly of sets without using the predicate "set", then it defines a set. The last axiom is that of infinity stating that every natural number is a set, where natural number is defined in the customary way as a finite von Neumann ordinal.

FORMAL EXPOSITION

To the language of set theory (first order logic with equality and membership) add a primitive one place predicate symbol $``set"$, denoting *"is a set"*.

**Axioms:**

**Extensionality:** $\forall x \forall y [\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y]$

**Sethood:** $\forall x [set(x) \leftrightarrow \forall y \in x (set(y))]$

**Comprehension:** if $\phi$ is a formula in the langauge of set theory (i.e. doesn't use the symbol $``set"$), in which the symbol $``x"$ is not free, then all closures of:$$ \forall y (\phi \to set(y)) \to \exists x \forall y \ (y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi)$$; are axioms.

**Infinity:** $\forall n \ [natural(n) \to set(n)]$

Where $natural$ is defined as *finite von Neumann ordinal*, like as "well founded transitive sets of transitive sets, that are successors and every non empty element of them is a successor"

> Questions:
>
> 1. Is this theory consistent?
> 2. If it is consistent, is it interpretable in ZFC?
> 3. If 2, would it interpret ZFC?

This theory [if consistent] does interpret and prove the consistency of Zermelo set theory, over set $V_{\omega+\omega}$. I'd conjecture that it is equi-interpretable with ZFC also?! However, this theory might be inconsistent. Although this theory does prove existence of non-set classes, but it doesn't stipulate comprehension axioms about them. This is deliberately done here as to avoid set theoretic paradoxes since Sethood axiom is more powerful than the two completeness axioms of Ackermann's set theory, and also comprehension is not restricted to set parameters as it is the case with Ackermann's.
So this theory is hazardous. It would be nice to see if it is consistent! and also it would be nice to see what its exact strength relative to Ackermann's and ZFC!

Comment: 1) You need to give the details of your definition of von Neumann ordinal. 2) You haven't provided any substitute for the axiom of replacement, so $V_{\omega+\omega}$ would be a model of your system.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comprehension axiom: it probably is as strong as or stronger than replacement, so you probably shouldn't call it comprehension.

Comment: @RobArthan, I'll define the von Neumann's. Regarding the second point zermelo set theory does prove induction, and so by induction all elements of finite iterative powers of zero are sets, and so the set of all of them is the set HF of all hereditarily finite sets, by the same argument you get the set of all finite iterative powers of HF, which is a model of Zermelo and of course you clearly get $V_{\omega+\omega}$ being a set by separation.

Comment: @RobArthan, well anyway the original comprehension axiom of Naive set theory is indeed stronger than replacement, since its inconsistent. Anyhow I'm not really sure if it is stronger than replacement, since it forbids "set" from being used, so the quantifiers cannot be bounded by the predicate "set", and so this might limit replacements.

Comment: I think the most dangerous feature of this theory is that it doesn't limit its parameters to being sets, and I think an inconsistency would lie there! of course this is remediable easily by requiring parameter to be sets.

Comment: I've bountied the question. If you have any amendments or improvements you can edit the question and that will raise it to the front page.

Comment: @user76284. Thanks!

Comment: Can we simplify the axiom of infinity to $\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y)$ or something similarly simple, while retaining consistency?

Comment: @user76284 do you mean like $\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow set(y))$, call this defined class as $V$, then yes but by then you need to bound all parameters in comprehension by $V$.

Comment: @Zuhair Oops. Yes, that's what I meant. Don't know why the set predicate disappeared.

Comment: @Zuhair Can you expand on what you mean by needing to bound the comprehension parameters? In case you're interested in taking a look, there's a [Logic chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic) where we're discussing these questions.

Comment: @user76284 by then this would become the same as the following question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354733/can-ackermann-theory-minus-foundation-minus-class-comprehension-permit-allowing

Comment: I wonder whether something similarly short to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3207882/76284) could suffice as the axiom of infinity.

Comment: @user76284, there are short formulations of infinity, I didn't know of the one you've referred to, but I read it and it heavily relies on FOUNDATION, without foundation the Quine atom would fulfill $S$. A short definition that doesnt' require axiom of regularity is presented below with around 14 occurrences of variables in it (compared to 9 in the one you've referred). Possibly we can combine the formulation you wrote with foundation to make a shorter axiom? 1. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299666/what-is-the-shortest-expression-of-finiteness

Comment: @Zuhair Is the definition of $\mathsf{natural}$ you originally had in mind when you wrote the question the same as this one? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity#Extracting_the_natural_numbers_from_the_infinite_set

Comment: I think the axiom $\forall x \exists y (\mathsf{set} \, y \land x \in y \land \forall z (z \in y \rightarrow \exists w (z \in w \land w \in y)))$ might be suitable (it can be applied to the empty set that is constructed with $\phi = \bot$).

Comment: @user76284 I already defined what "natural" means, it is a finite von Neumann ordinal, i.e. a well founded transitive set of transitive sets that is a successor and every non-empty element of it is a successor.

Comment: @user76284 what do you mean by 'set" in your last proposed axiom. If it means the primitive stipulated her then it is false, since this theory proves existence of non-set objects, and by set-hood axiom there is no set y that has a non-set object as an element of it.

Comment: @user76284, your last proposed axiom requires foundation also, since without it we can have finite cyclic sets and this would evade infinity. For example we can take the statement that for any set x there is a set $y$ such that: $y=\{x,y\}$ to be true.

Comment: @Zuhair I'm not sure I understand your first comment. Would you like to [discuss in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic)?

Comment: @user76284 I personally think that the *shortest* expression of infinity is: there exists a non empty set x that is closed under existence of proper superset, i.e. for every element y of x there exists an element z of x such that z is a proper superset of  y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This theory is consistent and moreover its consistency strength is below that of ZFC.

Note that if any model of that theory is is necessary illfounded from the outside. To see this, take any $x_0$ that does not satisfy the $set$-predicate (this must exist). Then it has to contain an element $x_0\in x_1$ that does not satisfy the $set$-predicate as well and one can continue the chain indefinatley. This gives us a hint how we can find such a model.

Let us take any $\omega$-wellfounded, yet illfounded model $(M, E)$ of Zermelo Set theory plus the statment "the von-Neumann Hierachy exists (as sets) and exhausts the whole universe". Observe that ZFC proves such models to exist. Let $\operatorname{wfc}(M)$ denote the wellfounded part of $M$, i.e. all sets in $M$ that are not part of an infinite descending $\in$-chain (from the outside). We may assume that $(M, E)$ is *solid* in the sense that $\operatorname{wfc}(M)$ is transitive and that the $E$-relation agrees with the true $\in$-relation on $\operatorname{wfc}(M)$. I claim that the structure $\mathcal M=(M; E, set)$ satisfies your theory when we interpret $set$ as $\operatorname{wfc}(M)$.

The Extensionality axiom clearly holds true.

The Sethood axiom is true as any element $x_0$ of the illfounded part of $M$ has an element in the illfounded part of $M$, for example the $x_1$ of any infinite descending chain $x_0\ Ǝ\ x_1\ Ǝ\dots$.

The Infinity axiom holds true as we chose $M$ to be $\omega$-wellfounded, i.e. $\omega^M\subseteq\operatorname{wfc}(M)$.

Now finally lets see that your Comprehension scheme holds as well. Suppose $\varphi(y)$ is any $\in$-formula that has the property
$$\mathcal M\models\forall y\ \varphi(y)\rightarrow set(y)$$
I claim that there is an ordinal $\alpha\in\operatorname{wfc}(M)$ such that any $y\in M$ satisfying $\varphi$ has $M$-rank $<\alpha$. Suppose not. Let $\delta=\operatorname{Ord}\cap\operatorname{wfc}(M)$. That means that $\{\operatorname{rank}(y)\mid \varphi(y)\}^M$ is contained and unbounded in $\delta$. Hence $\delta$ is definable over $M$ as the union over this class.  But this is impossible: There would be an element $x$ of $M$ whose elements are exactly that of $\delta$. Then $x$ is an $M$-ordinal and furthermore it is in the wellfounded part of $M$, hence $x\in\operatorname{Ord}\cap\operatorname{wfc}(M)=\delta$ and so $x E x$, a contradiction. This is one manifestation of the *overspill principle*. 
Thus there is such an $\alpha$. But then 
$$\{y\mid\varphi(y)\}^M=\{y\in V_\alpha\mid \varphi(y)\}^M$$
and the latter class is a set in $M$ by seperation (here we use that our assumption that $V_\alpha$ is a set). Note that even the version of the comprehension scheme with parameters is true here as long as we require the parameters to fulfill the $set$-predicate(EDIT: Actually we dont need this restriction).

Comment: but parameters are allowed here (all closures refer to universal quantification over those parameters) I didn't restrict $\phi$ to parameter free formulas, actually this theory has parameters and they are unbounded (not necessarily fulfilling the $set$-predicat), and its here where I suspected this theory to be inconsistent!? But if bounding the parameters by the $set$-predicate is the solution  then that's an easy fix! Is the theory with the parameters unleashed (which is what's presented) consistent? That's the question.

Comment: Upon further reflection, it the model in my answer satisfies your theory even when parameters in the illfounded part are allowed. The point is that $\delta$ is not definable in $M$ in *any* parameters, not sure why I thought this was necessary. So yes the theory is consistent .